Filter polars DataFrame where values starts with any string in a list
I have a DataFrame with a few million rows, e.g.:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['12345', '12', '54467899', '5433523353','0024355']
})

And a list of a couple hundred prefixes such as:
prefixes = ['123', '544', '55443345']

Is there an efficient way to filter the large DataFrame to only retain values where col1 starts with any of the prefixes in the prefixes list.
I.e. the original frame:
┌────────────┐
│ col1       │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 12345      │
│ 12         │
│ 54467899   │
│ 5433523353 │
│ 0024355    │
└────────────┘

is filtered down to
┌────────────┐
│ col1       │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 12345      │
│ 54467899   │
└────────────┘

Edit: I have tried (with the real prefixes list, about 600 items)
   prefix_regex = '|'.join(f"^{prefix}" for prefix in prefixes)
   ldf = pl.scan_parquet('./data.parquet')
   ldf = ldf.filter(pl.col("col1").str.contains(prefix_regex)).collect()

It's still sitting here not finished 5 minutes later. Without the filter collects in a few seconds.

what did you try? and what was the performance?

Unlike to be a performance game changer, but I would use: prefix_regex = fr'^({"|".join(prefixes)})'.

There is a dedicated .str.starts_with() expression.
You can use .any_horizontal() to build a chain of "OR" conditions.
prefix_filter = pl.any_horizontal(
    pl.col("col1").str.starts_with(prefix) for prefix in prefixes
)

df.filter(prefix_filter)

shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────┐
│ col1     │
│ ---      │
│ str      │
╞══════════╡
│ 12345    │
│ 54467899 │
└──────────┘


The simplest fast solution will almost surely be a filter with a single regex. Make sure to only include the start character ^ once, I believe this gives the best performance of the regex builder:
prefix_regex = '^({})'.format('|'.join(prefixes))
df.filter(pl.col.col1.str.contains(prefix_regex)).collect()


Why can we include the start character ^ only once? I thought the pattern ^ab|cd checks if the string starts with ab or if it contains cd.

@Hericks Oops I edited my answer, that should be ^(ab|cd).

Makes sense. I benchmarked the code and having only a single ^ character does give a 10% runtime improvement (in contrast to the disjunction of patterns all containing ^)!

no need for rexeg ...
given your inputs
df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: any(x.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes))]
       col1
0     12345
2  54467899



not sure who's -1 my suggestion, but at least comment why.

Probably because the question about Polars - but your answer is for Pandas.

doh, age related brain fa*t

apologies for my sloppy initial response,  from functools import reduce
df.filter(reduce(lambda dfc, pre: dfc| pre, [pl.col('col1').str.starts_with(prefix) for prefix in prefixes]))  , no idea if its faster than using a regex.
